# Line in Libre office Calc Burndown chart doesn't start at same data point, why?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, burndowncharts

I'm having trouble with the Data Series of the *"Actual hrs left"* line (the red one in the picture below). Can you please help me fix this problem?
Here are 2 snapshots that might help you help me.

[image: error in burn down chart in Calc L.Office]

[image: data ranges "Actual hrs left"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck [Stack series](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Chart_Type_Line) when creating the chart.  Like this:

[image: stack series unchecked]

Not like this:

[image: stack series checked]